# a strange relative path (../) issue with ajax call to read an xml file

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, relative-path

I am using ajax to read the contents of an xml file.  If I keep all the files (html, xml, and jquery resource) in the same folder than the ajax code works with url: 'glossary.xml'

However, I need to keep the html file inside a folder named 'file' and the xml file inside a folder named 'glossary'.  Look likes this:

root->file->index.html    and
root->glossary->glossary.xml

I do not know why the code (url: '../glossary/glossary.xml') below does not work.  Do you have any idea?

```
$(document).ready(function () {             
                $(".glossary_item").click(function(e) {

                    var term = $(this).text();
                    $.ajax(
                    {
                        type: "GET",
                        url: '../glossary/glossary.xml',
                        dataType: "xml",
                        success: function(xml) {
                            $(xml).find('terms').each(function() 
                            {                               
                                if($(this).find('term').text().trim() == term)
                                {
                                    $('#definition').text($(this).find('term').next().text());
                                }                               
                            });                  
                        }
                    });
                });         
            });
```

Comment: **How** doesn't it work?

Comment: Is the glossary xml file accessible via the web browser address bar? If not, then it also isn't accessible via ajax.

Comment: @SLaks whenever I need to use ../  to indicate a relative path, then xml file is null, it can not read the source file.  But, for example, if html file is in the root, and the xml file is in the glossary folder then this line works great url: 'glossary/glossary.xml'  in other cases it does not work

Comment: @KevinB you mean I can not use relative url?  I am just testing this in DW in my computer.  It also does not work in the server as well.  I do not wanna use absolute url since I will need this code later in other projects.

Comment: What do you see in the network tab?

Comment: Yes, you can use a relative url, but, the location must be accessible via normal browsing. If you can't get to it by typing a url directly into the browser, neither can ajax.

Comment: @SLaks I can displaythe xml file using FF with this url file:///C:/jquery-glossary-xml/glossary/glossary.xml   but when I put it in the code url: 'file:///C:/jquery-glossary-xml/glossary/glossary.xml'   it does not work ...

Comment: For example, if your web root is `root->file`, you can't access anything inside of `root->glossary`

Comment: Don't test using the filesystem... use a webserver.

Comment: Any path you have in a Javascript/Ajax call is being used in the context of the client browser, not the server.  The "../" will be interpreted relative to the page's URL.  If the page's URL is `http://my.server.tld/aa/bb/cc/index.html` your relative URL will be seen as `http://my.server.tld/aa/bb/glossary/glossary.xml`.  If that URL is not retrievable the Ajax call will fail.